# Why deleting variable in python can not release memory?

Tags: ubuntu

I use delete to get rid of large variables in python to release memory. But when i use free-g to check the memory, there is no change. The system is ubuntu. I am not sure what happend. I use the same way to release in MacOs and it succeed. Is there anything I missed in Ubuntu?

Comment: Are your variables global, or do they only exist in the span of a function?

Comment: Not in function.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to do it in two steps:

1. use the command *del* to remove the variable from the workspace
2. use the comand *gc.collect* to run the garbage collector and clear the ram memory

A code example:

```
import numpy as np
import gc

a = np.array([1,2,3])
del a
gc.collect()
```

More info: [link](https://www.delftstack.com/howto/python/python-clear-memory/)